# How to find methods with an annotation in a class?

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

Given an annotation

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class MyAnnotation
```

How to find methods with this annotation?

This is how far I got:

```
val cls = myObject.javaClass.kotlin
val found = cls.memberFunctions.filter { it.annotations.contains( ??? ) }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The annotation will be the instance of your `MyAnnotation` class. Therefore, all you need to do is:

```
cls.memberFunctions.filter { it.annotations.any { anno -> anno is MyAnnotation } }
```